# Test Distribution Difference between small sample sizes

Tags: hypothesis-testing, small-sample, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, fraud-detection

My first post of StackExchange.

I am working on data analysis project for comparison of fraud and nonfraud transactions. My objective is to compare the feature vectors of nonfraud transactions and compare them to fraud transactions. For this I am computing similarity scores between nonfraud and fraud transactions based on their feature vectors using Euclidean Distance. This similarity computation happens on groups of nonfraud and fraud transactions (e.g if they share some identifiers such as same last 4 digits of credit card, they are in the same group).

Since I want to make a decision of flag/no flag on a nonfraud transaction based on their similarity to other fraud transactions in that group, **I want to compare the similarity distribution of a nonfraud transaction (to other fraud transactions in that cluster) vs the similarity distribution of fraud transactions with themselves (take only the upper triangle of the fraud-fraud similarity matrix)**.

Based on this comparison, I can flag if the distributions are not statistically significantly different (meaning the nonfraud have similar distributions)

For this, I used a two-sample KS Test. But some groups have less than 10 fraud samples (e.g 3-4 fraud transactions and 1 nonfraud transaction).
My questions:

1. So can I still use the KS Test even when there are very small number of samples? This probably results in lower power and make conclusion unreliable.
2. Can i bootstrap the samples to say size 20 or 50 and apply the test?

I am not sure what is the correct direction to take and looking for guidance.